# Javascript create a new upload image form on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am looking to create a button, that when onclick to create a new image upload button like this and put that within a form that i have created in html. I am wondering how to approach this, because there is a remove button, so if the remove button is clicked, it will remove the image selected for that button (class="btn btn-file").

If it is complex to do such function? I am not sure how to create the  with all the details in Javascript, Or should i just have a choose file button and if the user want to remove the image, they just select something blank to remove the image.

```
<div class="control-group">
    <span class="btn btn-file">
        <input id="chosenfile" type="file"  name="file" />
    </span>
    <a href="#" id="remove" class="btn fileupload-exists" 
       data-dismiss="fileupload">Remove</a>
    <div class="controls"></div>
</div>
</script>
<script  >
    var addnew = document.getElementById('add');

    addnew.addEventListener('click', function() {
        var f = document.createElement("btn btn-file");
        var f1 =  document.createElement("control-group");
    },false);
</script>
<script  >
    $('#remove').click(function(){
        $('#chosenfile').val('');
    })
</script>
```

Comment: What is the short version of this question? You want to `clone` the whole upload form on the click of a button?

Comment: You are using `createElement` wrong, it takes the name of an element not a class selector. So: `"div"`,`"span"`,`"iframe"`,etc are valid, `"btn btn-file"` is not, unless you are using custom elements even then `btn btn-file` would cause your script to throw an error, not to mention you are not doing anything with them after creating them.

Comment: @putvande Yes i want to clone the whole upload but not the form just the upload image part, so it starts off with a list and 1 choose image button, and with a Add more button, when the Add more button is clicked, another choose image button appears

Answer (score 0):

The string passed to document.createElement function must be a tag name.

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_document_createelement.asp

The code inside your 'click' event listener should be this way:

```
var f = document.createElement("button");
f.className = "btn btn-file";

var f1 =  document.createElement("IM-NOT-SURE-WHAT-TAG-YOU-WANT");
f1.className = "control-group";
```

More about changing CSS class for elements:

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_html_classname.asp

Comment: This does not actually solve OP's problem, just points out an error in his code.

Comment: i think i kind of understand what that link means on this http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_html_classname.asp i will give it a go, just wonder if i can use the document.write() to create this <a href="#" id="remove" class="btn btn-default fileinput-exists" data-dismiss="fileinput">Remove</a>?